# scrapy File (unknown-error): Error downloading image from <GET http://www.xxx.jpg> referred in <None>: 'splash'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to download an image with scrapy using splash. When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
2019-04-09 11:09:32 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (unknown-error): Error downloading image from <GET https://www.xxxxx.jpg> referred in <None>: 'splash'
```

I tried using SplashRequest, but failed. What should I do? See my code below:

```
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        try:
            for image_url in item['image']:
                yield SplashRequest(image_url,endpoint='render.html' )
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Splash is a JavaScript pre-rendering service. Do not use Splash to download images, or binary files in general, use regular Scrapy requests instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#usage), SplashRequest requires **two** arguments: `url` and `self.parse_result`. The rest are optional:

```
yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result,
    args={
        # optional; parameters passed to Splash HTTP API
        'wait': 0.5,

        # 'url' is prefilled from request url
        # 'http_method' is set to 'POST' for POST requests
        # 'body' is set to request body for POST requests
    },
    endpoint='render.json', # optional; default is render.html
    splash_url='<url>',     # optional; overrides SPLASH_URL
    slot_policy=scrapy_splash.SlotPolicy.PER_DOMAIN,  # optional
)
```

In your code, you're not providing the `self.parse_result` argument. You need to pass the name of your parse method. For example, if your parse method is called `parse`, then use:

```
yield SplashRequest(image_url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html' )
```